# Can "acceptance" become a Defense Mechanism?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, consciousness, depression, unconscious

Most of the Defense Mechanisms are unconscious, but for those who know about them and still use then it somehow becomes conscious. They know they are using it, and not do anything about it. For example when one loses trust in everyone around them, but they tell everyone who understands about their secret or something that shouldn't be shared easily; Reaction Formation, yes.
So, when, let's say, someone has mood swings, they cry when a bit depressed or even just sad, and laugh like there's no tomorrow when they're happy, even if it's the moment right after their cry, or just shout out loud because they are angry while they are generally a calm person. They simply let it all sink in and accept everything that comes, without doing anything about it, even though they know they should, and they know where the wrong is. 
So can't it be set as one?

Comment: Acceptance **can form part** of a defence mechanism, but not be a defence mechanism in itself.  Acceptance can be part of any of the 6 defence mechanisms mentioned in [my answer to another question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/20205)